# search and replace string using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

i have a sed command like this for search and replace string inside a file:

```
sed -i -e 's/`db1`./`db2`./g' result/files1.sql
```

that is working fine to replace the db1 to db2 inside the file of: result/files1.sql

however when i change it to bash and variable format, it does not work.

```
sed -i -e "s/`${mydbname}`./`${mydbname2}`./g" "${mypath}"
```

i get error like:

```
./mycoolscript: line 241: db1: command not found
./mycoolscript: line 241: db2: command not found
```

any solution would be great.

Comment: Why do you need to add ` around ${mydbname} ? It makes the second sed commands think db1 is a command rather than a string you want to replace. Note that shell will replace any variables including `COMMAND` inside "" (quote), but will not replace inside '' (single quote).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the backtick character

```
sed -i -e "s/\`${mydbname}\`./\`${mydbname2}\`./g" "${mypath}"
```

Bash treats the part within backticks as a command and first executes that.

Answer (score 3):

If `is something you need to replace, you will need to escape` by . Here it is

```
sed -i -e "s/\`${mydbname}\`./\`${mydbname2}\`./g" "${mypath}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sed -i -e "s/${mydbname}/${mydbname2}/g" "${mypath}"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more way, of using single quotes for literals & double quotes only around variables/escape sequences.

```
sed -i -e 's/`'"${mydbname}"'`./`'"${mydbname2}"'`./g' "${mypath}"
```

Because of single quotes, you will not have to escape the special characters.

The trade-off between escaping special characters vs. using mix of single & double quotes would depend on number of special characters vs. number of variables.

If there are too many characters that would need escaping & less number of variables, I would prefer mix of single & double quotes.